# Algorithm to mark loss of precision on doubles in C++ does not mark the correct positions

Tags: c++, c++11

As part of one of my classes, I'm supposed to demonstrate possible loss of precision for double division using C++ by printing the result of `1./3.` to 20 decimal places and marking the positions where the digit is not 3.

However, the algorithm I have (which I have listed below) seems to keep running into the same runtime error.

I've left the code below and the expected and actual outputs below. Is there a way around this? I've tried alternative methods (including `ostringstream` from `<sstream>`) but this is the most accurate one I've been able to come up with so far.

---

**The algorithm**

1. Store the result of `1./3.` to a variable.
2. Print out `1./3.` to 20 decimal places & add an appropriate spacer.
3. Multiply the variable in step 1 by 10 (i.e. shift all digits left one place).
4. Check that the ones digit is 3. If it is, print ; otherwise, print `^`.
5. Decrement the ones place until the ones position is 0.
6. Repeat steps 3-6 19 more times.

---

**Expected output**

```
1./3. Precision test
1./3.: 0.33333333333333331483
                         ^^^
```

---

**Actual output (with debugging output)**

```
1./3. Precision test
1./3.: 0.33333333333333331483
                         ^ ^^
         33333333333333330372
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double third = 1./3.;
    cout << "1./3. Precision test" << endl;
    cout << setw(7) << "1./3.: " << setprecision(20) << third << endl;
    cout << "         ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        third *= 10;
        if (int(third) == 3)
            cout << " ";
        else
            cout << "^";
        while (third >= 1) third -= 1;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // For debugging purposes
    third = 1./3.;
    cout << "         ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        third *= 10;
        cout << int(third);
        while (third > 1) third -= 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: @Drop I didn't do that before, but after running a debugger, it appears that the number changes after the first iteration of `third *= 10;` .

Comment: Your expected output is bizarre... in `0.33333333333333331483`, the final `3` is worse than a `4` or more - why would you stop underlining after it's started to deviate from 3?

Comment: Well, you should always run a debugger session before you post a question. Also note, that you are measuring precision loss of 1 division, but ignoring 10 precision losses of multiplications.

Comment: @Tony The professor wants it that way. Since he's the one ultimately in charge of giving me the grades, what he says, goes.

Comment: Depending on what your teacher expects, you might convert this number to a string, and operate on it (as @RobL described), or you might operate on binary representation of `double` type. If your course syllabus says something about [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), the second solution is more likely expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've fallen trap to precision problems.  If you repeatedly multiply 1/3 by 10, this is what you get:

```
    0.33333333333333331483
    3.3333333333333330373
    33.333333333333328596
    333.33333333333325754
    3333.3333333333325754
    33333.333333333328483
    333333.33333333325572
    3333333.3333333325572
    33333333.333333324641
    333333333.33333325386
    3333333333.3333325386
    33333333333.333324432
    333333333333.33325195
    3333333333333.3325195
    33333333333333.324219
    333333333333333.25
    3333333333333332.5
    33333333333333324
    333333333333333248
    3333333333333332480
    33333333333333323776
```

Notice that the last digits are changing.  You need to convert to a string first, something like this:

```
    double third = 1. / 3.;
    cout << "1./3. Precision test" << endl;
    ostringstream s;
    cout << setw(7) << "1./3.: ";
    s << setprecision(20) << third << endl;
    string str = s.str();
    cout << str;
    cout << "         ";
    for (int i = 2; i <= 21; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '3')
            cout << " ";
        else
            cout << "^";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: I feel like a bloody idiot. I tried using `ostringstream` from `<sstream>` before and it didn't end up working. And now it does. I must've screwed up somewhere on my earlier attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can access the precision of a double with:

```
#include <limits>
std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;
```

This gives 15 on my linux 64 bits machine.

Then, when you multiply by 10, you change the number because only multiplying by 2 is an exact operation in base2 which is the internal representation of the number.